# I Have a List of unique devices and 4 different tariffs to create a new list with 1 row per device and tariff

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a List with unique Device names and 4 different tariffs: tariff 1, 2, 3 and 4

I want to create a list that has one row for each combination of the devices and tariffs so a total of 4 rows per device.

Example:

Device 1 | Tariff 1

Device 1 | Tariff 2

.
.

Device 3 | Tariff 1

Device 3 | Tariff 2

Is there any quick and easy way to do it?

Edit: I want this to be in two seperate columns so Column A: Devices, Column B: Tariffs

Comment: Outer loop the Device names and inner loop the tariffs and perform a concatenation inside

Comment: Yes. There is. Where are you stuck / what is the programming question / what code do you have so far?

Comment: @Qharr just saw I was not clear on the fact that I dont need them Concatenated but in seperate columns, so one column as Device Name and one column as Tariff Name. Is this still the best option?

Comment: @Rik Sportel Well so far I was hoping this would somehow be easy without VBA, I tried using some sort of Index Match that goes through the unique device list, but only going to the next device after tariff 4 has been reached, but was not very successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Combinations()
    Dim i As Long, y As Long, counter As Long
    counter = 2

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For i = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row '<== Loop devices skipping header
            For y = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row '<== Loop tariffs skipping header
                .Cells(counter, "C") = .Cells(i, "A")
                .Cells(counter, "D") = .Cells(y, "B")
                counter = counter + 1
            Next y
        Next i
   End With
End Sub
```

Example output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Thank you @QHarr adapting and testing your code right now! It works perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It's super easy with Power Query (get & transform data) - if you put your list of Devices in one table, and your list of Tariffs in another:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tbDevices"]}[Content],
    Tariffs = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tbTariffs"]}[Content],
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each Tariffs),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", {"Tariffs"}, {"Tariffs"})
in
    #"Expanded Custom"
```

For example:

[image: For example:]